# Trying to find distance using a 9dof imu

Tags: java, accelerometer, gyroscope, magnetometer

I am doing a research project to determine, acceleration, velocity, and distance of a weightlifting bar doing a clean. I have looked into using a 9dof imu sensor, however I have found out that calculating the distance the bar has traveled is not accurate, since the sensor is not always parallel during the lift to the ground and issues with the double integral.  I have thought about using an ultrasonic range finder to get the distance however, if connected to the bar we run into the same problem as above.  I would like some other ideas.

Comment: I have seen a device for determining position and velocity base on ultrasonic measurements. It worked just fine. I would say you are on the right track. What problems did you encounter exactly? Apart from ultrasonic measurements, you may consider [Kinect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinect) if it is some indoor application.

Comment: The ultrasonic device needs to be installed by the collar but the collar moves freely that's an issue how to keep the ultrasonic pointing to the ground.